# fscanf to extract multiple integers of various sizes in a file

Tags: c

I have a text file that I'm trying to pull out all the integers and place them into an array.  The integers are of varying sizes, and may include commas and decimals (if a decimal is present, I'd truncate the fraction).
Here's the text from the file:

```
This is a test text file...
This is line 2.
This could be line 3.
Ben Franklin was here.
Blah!
Pi is 3.1415
The dinosaurs died 65,000,000 years ago.
I am 31 years old.
Our baby's due date is the 9th of April.
Tom's bday is 9/1/1986
```

Any way I can make an array of something like:
`[2, 3, 3, 65000000, 31, 9, 9, 1, 1986]`?

Original code used `getc()`, but this didn't work, as it only pulled out one-digit at a time.

```
int find_ints(FILE *fp, int arr[])
{
  int ch, num = 0;

  while((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if(isdigit(ch)) {
      *arr++ = ch - '0';
      num++;
    }
  }

  return num;
}
```

> Would using fscanf be a better way?

If so, can someone please walk me through it a bit?  I had this at first, but it only grabbed the very first `int`.

```
fscanf(fp, "%*[0123456789,]%d", arr)
```

Comment: It seems a bit loose. Suppose there is floating point number in the form `1e9`? And suppose there is a date in the form `26.3.2016`? Suppose there is the phrase `could be 64,65 items`. Suppose there is a negative number? I suggest reading char by char until you meet a digit, then you process a number until it's done by your rules. How to accumulate a number? `int number = 0;` then for each digit `number = number * 10 + ch - '0';`

Comment: What do you mean by "integers of various sizes" ?

Comment: *Would using fscanf be a better way?* **No.** Using `fscanf` when the rows your are reading have potentially differing content is *rarely*, *if ever* a better choice. Your choices are *character-oriented* input (as you are doing with `fgetc`) where you react to each character as they are read, or *line-oriented* input (such as `fgets` or `getline`) where you read a line  at a time and parse the resulting buffer with either `sscanf` or walking a pointer down the string. `fscanf` for problems like this is like trying to cram a *round peg in a square hole*.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good exercise for you to think through, but you must take it step-by-step, and account for all character-contingencies you will encounter reading your file a character at a time.

The two primary approaches you can take are to (1) read each char, and if a digit, perform a conversion and intermediate sum to build the value of the integer, or (perhaps easier) (2) add each digit to a *character-array* and when you reach a non-digit, *nul-terminate* and convert the character-array to an integer using `atoi` or `strtol`. I find the second a bit easier. (otherwise, you need to handle the intermediate-sum for each digit encountered)

Taking the second approach, you could write your `findints` something similar to:

```
int findints (FILE *fp, int *arr, size_t sz)
{
    int c, n = 0, idx = 0;
    char tmp[MAXD] = "";

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) {       /* for each char    */
        if (c == ',')                       /* get next if ,    */
            continue;
        if (idx && !isdigit(c)) {           /* if end of digits */
            tmp[idx] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate    */
            arr[n++] = (int) strtol (tmp, NULL, BASE);  /* convert to int */
            idx = 0;                        /* reset idx */
            memset (tmp, 0, sizeof tmp);    /* reset tmp */
            if (n == (int)sz) {             /* validate sz < MAXSZ */
                fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXSZ reached.\n");
                break;
            }
            if (c == '.')   /* truncate after '.' */
                while (isdigit ((c = fgetc (fp)))) {}
        }
        if (isdigit (c))    /* add digit to char array */
            tmp[idx++] = c;
    }

    return n;
}
```

There are probably improvements you can make, but take the time and step through it *line-by-line* and *character-by-character* to understand the testing done and how the character array is built, converted and reset, how the decimal truncation is done for numbers containing a `'.'`, etc..

You can test the code on your datafile with a short program that calls `findints`. *note:* the code with read from the file given as the first argument (or from `stdin` if no filename is give by default).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum { BASE = 10, MAXD = 21, MAXSZ = 128 };

int findints (FILE *fp, int *arr, size_t sz);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a[MAXSZ] = {0}, i, n = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    n = findints (fp, a, MAXSZ);    /* call findints */

    printf ("\n the array has '%d' elements.\n\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  array[%2d] : %d\n", i, a[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}

int findints (FILE *fp, int *arr, size_t sz)
{
    int c, n = 0, idx = 0;
    char tmp[MAXD] = "";

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) {       /* for each char    */
        if (c == ',')                       /* get next if ,    */
            continue;
        if (idx && !isdigit(c)) {           /* if end of digits */
            tmp[idx] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate    */
            arr[n++] = (int) strtol (tmp, NULL, BASE);  /* convert to int */
            idx = 0;                        /* reset idx */
            memset (tmp, 0, sizeof tmp);    /* reset tmp */
            if (n == (int)sz) {             /* validate sz < MAXSZ */
                fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXSZ reached.\n");
                break;
            }
            if (c == '.')   /* truncate after '.' */
                while (isdigit ((c = fgetc (fp)))) {}
        }
        if (isdigit (c))    /* add digit to char array */
            tmp[idx++] = c;
    }

    return n;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/txt2array <dat/getint.txt

 the array has '9' elements.

  array[ 0] : 2
  array[ 1] : 3
  array[ 2] : 3
  array[ 3] : 65000000
  array[ 4] : 31
  array[ 5] : 9
  array[ 6] : 9
  array[ 7] : 1
  array[ 8] : 1986
```

As you discover or encounter additional cases (as pointed out in the comment), you can refine your `findints` process to do what it is you would like it to do. One such case, not addressed in you original datafile would be the case where there is a leading `'.'` followed by digits (e.g. `.nnn` (say `.1234`)). Since your original question truncated all decimals, above should evaluate to `0`, but `0` is a valid integer value. So you could decide to treat any fractional parts as if they were `0.1234` which would be `0` in the original statement, but would nevertheless be added to the array in its own right.

So you would need a test for `'.'` when no digits had been added to your character array. The case where digits exist before a `'.'` is encountered is already covered by `if (idx && !isdigit(c))`, so you need only add something like:

```
while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF) {       /* for each char    */
    ...
    if (idx && !isdigit(c)) {           /* if end of digits */
        ...
    }
    /* consider '.nnn' as 0 */
    if (c == '.' && isdigit ((c = fgetc (fp)))) {
        while (isdigit ((c = fgetc (fp)))) {}
        arr[n++] = 0;
    }
    ...
```

That is the benefit of building your own parsing routine, you can tailor it to do exactly what you need it to do and add to it when you encounter additional cases that need to be addressed.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Corner case: What should `.123` become: `0` ?  (it is a number including a decimal) or `123`  Nice answer btw

Comment: Nonetheless a valid corner case. According to the question, truncating everything following the `'.'` would result in `0`, but since `0` is a valid integer, that should probably end up in the array. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David.  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

- `fgets(strbuff, sizeof(strbuff), fp)`
- replace all tokens (ie `/` ) with spaces.
- remove all commas (`,`) and trailing `/n`
- use `strtok()`
- parse each token with `atof()`
- store `atof()` result as a `long long int`
- repeat for each token
- repeat for each line.

Comment: This does not address processing needed for `.` and `,`.

Comment: if you "*replace all tokens (ie `/` ) with spaces*", your conversion will fail for `65,000,000` and `9/1/1986` as well as failing to truncate `3.1415`. You must handle the delimiters individually.

Comment: @DavidCRankin `.` is handled by atof and casting to int. `,` needs to be removed, not replaced by spaces, dates delimiters are replaced by spaces, strtok() does the rest.

Comment: Granted, your `'.'` is handled by the `atof` and subsequent cast to `int` would truncate the fractional part.

Answer (score -1):

First copy the lines(from file) into strings then you can use `"atoi(some_string)"` function that return the first integer that lies in `some_string`....I think it can help to make the array as you are hoping...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the input.  I really appreciate it.